# How to show that MA implies $\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{c}$?

Tags: set-theory

I can't find a proof for this online. Can somebody help me out?

We have the dominating number $\mathfrak{d} = \min\{|\mathcal{F}|: \mathcal{F} \text{ dominating family} \}$.

Now I am supposed to use Martins Axiom to show that $\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{c}$.

We know that $\mathfrak{d}\leq \mathfrak{c}$, so my idea was to assume $\mathfrak{d}<\mathfrak{c}$ and find a contradiction via MA. Maybe taking partial functions of functions in $\mathcal{F}$ as poset $P$ with $p\leq q$ when $p\subseteq q$. Then we know that $P$ satisfies ccc, but from here my attempts failed.

Or is there maybe a way to show that every free filter can be extended to a P-point with MA?

Comment: Maybe I am writing something completely wrong but why should we end up with a contradiction by assuming a statement we know to be true?

Comment: @Kolmin I wanted to assume $\mathfrak{d}<\mathfrak{c}$ and get to a contradiction to show that it must be $\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{c}$. Why do you think $\mathfrak{d}<\mathfrak{c}$ is true?

Comment: You write $\mathfrak{b} \leq \mathfrak{c}$ is true. Thus, I guess the equal part makes the job in your argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get your point.

Comment: Sorry, I read it just know. I was seeing ghosts, but my line was the following: we want to prove $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{c}$ and we know that $\mathfrak{b} \leq \mathfrak{c}$. Thus it remains to prove that $\mathfrak{b} \geq \mathfrak{c}$. We prove it by contradiction by assuming that $\mathfrak{b} < \mathfrak{c}$. But how are we supposed to find a contradiction if actually we know that $\mathfrak{b} \leq \mathfrak{c}$? Hence, my last statement "I guess the equal part makes the job in your argument", i.e., the fact that you assume that $\mathfrak{b}$ is *strictly* less than $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: I hope I clarified my point.

Comment: @Kolmin My question is about $\mathfrak{d}$, not $\mathfrak{b}$. "But how are we supposed to find a contradiction if actually we know that $\mathfrak{d}\leq \mathfrak{c}$?". Well, for example if we want to prove that $x=y$ for $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y=10$ and we know that $x\leq y$ but we also know that $x \not \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, we can assume that $x<y$ (which is not true) and find a contradiction, st. it must be $x=y$ for $x\leq y$ to be true. Right?

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I meant with the statement that "the equal part makes the job". A good reason to also add that I was seeing ghosts (plus – thanks also for pointing this out – mixing up fraktur fonts)! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to phrase this as a proof by contradiction. "$\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{c}$" is the same thing as saying "if $A\subseteq\omega^\omega$ has cardinality $<\mathfrak{c}$, then there is some $f\in\omega^\omega$ which escapes every $g\in A$." *(That is, no "small" set is "sufficient.")*

To prove this, you need to show how you can find such an $f$ for a given $A$. The most direct way to do this is to find some poset $\mathbb{P}$ such that:

- $\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c.
- A (sufficiently) $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter $G$ can be viewed as an element of $\omega^\omega$ (or if you prefer, has an associated $\gamma\in\omega^\omega$).
- For all $A\subseteq\omega^\omega$ of cardinality $<\mathfrak{c}$, there is an associated set $\mathcal{D}$ of dense subsets of $\mathbb{P}$ such that

  - $\mathcal{D}$ has cardinality $<\mathfrak{c}$, and
  - any $\mathcal{D}$-generic filter through $\mathbb{P}$ is (or yields) a function escaping every element of $A$.

Thinking of dense sets as requirements that need to be met, $\mathcal{D}$ should have an element (or a family of elements) for each $f\in A$, corresponding to the "escapes $f$" requirement, as well has a family of dense sets corresponding to the "builds a function" requirement. So:

> Can you find a $\mathbb{P}$ which builds a function $\omega\rightarrow\omega$, which it is "easy" to make escape a given function $\omega\rightarrow\omega$?

With luck, the $\mathbb{P}$ you come up with will be c.c.c. and will lead you quickly to a solution to the problem. If not, try a different one!

*HINT: In this case, our $\mathbb{P}$ is quite simple, so don't try to make things too complicated for yourself.*

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand everything you wrote, but I tried to construct such a poset, staying as simple as possible. My poset is the set of tuples $\{<x,y>:x,y\in \omega\}$ with the partial ordering $<x,y>\leq <x',y'>$ iff $x=x'$ and $y\leq y'$. Then I take for any $A\subset \omega ^\omega$ the set $D=\{\{<x,y>: y\geq \max f(x): f\in A\}: x\in \omega\}$, which I'm not sure is valid, but is dense and would yield a function that can't be dominated by a given function in A by $D$-generic filter - I think? Also this poset satisfies ccc, since there are at most $\omega$ antichains.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege No. The conditions in your forcing are far too simple, and a generic filter ultimately just looks like the set of all pairs $\langle x, y\rangle$ for $y\in\omega$, for some fixed $x\in\omega$. (This is a good exercise.) Your forcing should have as conditions "pieces" of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$ which can get bigger (= build more of the function you're interested in), not individual ordered pairs.

Comment: Oh, I see. My intent was that $D=\{D_x:x\in \omega\}$ where $D_x = \{<x,y>:y\geq maxf(x)\}$ for given f. Then if G is a $D$-generic filter, it intersects wich any $D_x$, so I could define a function from that. But yes, too simple. What do you mean by pieces? Partial functions? If I take partial finite functions and define $p\leq q \Leftrightarrow dom(p)\subset dom(q) \land q|_{dom(p)}=p$? I tried this but it didn't work. I think I have to define a function in another way. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege Actually that's it exactly (although you have the ordering the wrong way round: most texts treat "$p\le q$" as "$p$ is *stronger* than $q$"). Why did it not work?

Comment: Well, next time I should say "I didn't get it" instead of "it didn't work". I don't understand how a generic filter in this case can yield an escaping function without any additional sequences. Say I have $D$ as the set of partial functions that extend partial functions of A for value fixed $x\in \omega$.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege I don't quite understand either your first or second sentences. Think about it this way: suppose I have a condition $p=\langle 1, 3, 5\rangle$ and $f(3)=6$. Then consider the condition $q=\langle 1, 3, 5, 7\rangle$; we have $q(3)>f(3)$, so we've caused the function we're building to escape $f$ *once*. Now we just have to do that infinitely many times ...

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I guess I'm lacking some skills here. I'll try to work on it.